# Issue in sending email from contact us form

Tags: php, email, contactus

**mail.php**

```
 <?php    
function goback()
{ 
    header("refresh:5; url=index.php");
    exit;
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $comment = $_POST['comment'];
  $mob = $_POST['mob'];
  $email= $_POST['email'];

  $to ='xxx@company.net';
  $subject= 'Request callback form';
  $message ="Name: ".$name."\n".
            "Comment: ".$comment."\n".
            "Mobile: ".$mob."\n".
            "E-mail: ".$email;           


  if(mail($to, $subject, $message)){        
    echo "Sent successfully! Thank you. ".$name.
    ", We will contact you soon!";
    goback();
  }
else 
{
  echo "something went wrong";
}
}
?>
```

I am getting email from this form if I set email id to **xxx@company.net** or **xxx@gmail.com**, But if I set it to **xxx@company.com** then I didnt received any mail from contact us form ...

can anyone help to fix this?

any setting required in outlook like in gmail we have to set it to "less security" ??

Comment: Have you checked the spam folder to see if the message is there ?

Comment: Sending a mail is **not the same** as receiving a mail. You show us the code for sending it, but you have a problem with receiving it?

Comment: any error message?

Comment: Goli: I'd strongly encourage you to please download SwiftMailer (https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/) or one of the many other libraries out there for sending emails. It's safer!

Comment: See the `Return values` section [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: @Igor Ilic  checked no email in that folder..

Comment: @Alexandre Painchaud  no error msg

Comment: the problem was with godaddy setting ... Domain name with respective email id I have to set to......Remote Mail Exchanger... thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

you should use headers as well or you can use PHPMailer/SMTP (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) as well

```
$subject = 'Subject Here';
$from = 'From email';
$to = $email;       
$message = 'Your query has been successfully submitted';  

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <$from>" . "\r\n";

$mail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

if($mail){
   echo  "Done";
}else{
   echo "error";
}
```